# AS3 Getting an Error #1009 on a Timer variable

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm having Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  I'm not exactly sure how to solve this problem myself, I've traced to see if the object var enemySpawnTimer:Timer is actually null and it isn't.  So I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Anyway here is my code, it's a class I use to spawn blocks that fall from the top of the screen to the bottom and is removed from the stage once it reaches the bottom of the screen.

```
package scripts
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    public class EnemySpawner
    {
        var stageRef:Stage;
        var target:Player;

        //vector variables
        public static var vectorBlock:Vector.<Block> = new Vector.<Block>();

        //enemy variables
        public static var block:Block;

        //timer variables
        var enemySpawnTimer:Timer = new Timer(250);

        //score variables
        public static var pointsBlock:Number = 0;

        public function EnemySpawner(stageRef:Stage, target:Player)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.target = target;

            enemySpawnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, SpawnBlocks, false, 0, true);
            enemySpawnTimer.start();
        }

        private function SpawnBlocks(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            block = new Block(stageRef);
            pointsBlock = block.pointsGiven;

            vectorBlock.push(block);
            stageRef.addChild(block);

            block.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function Update(e:Event):void
        {
            //remove enemies when they pass the bottom of the stage
            for each(var block:Block in vectorBlock)
            {
                if(block.y > Bounds.rectH + block.height)
                {
                    RemoveFromList(block);
                }
            }

            target.addEventListener("playerDeath", StopSpawning, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function RemoveFromList(block:Block):void
        {
            vectorBlock.splice(vectorBlock.indexOf(block), 1);

            if(stageRef.contains(block))
            {
                stageRef.removeChild(block);
            }
        }

        private function StopSpawning(e:Event):void
        {
            enemySpawnTimer.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get, unfortunately using the script editor in flash is not too helpful with where or what is causing the error exactly.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at scripts::EnemySpawner/SpawnBlocks()
at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Comment: It's probably not the Timer causing your null pointer exception.  Does the error message say anything else, do you have line numbers or anything?

Comment: I added the error.  Unfortunately I don't get line numbers unless its an error at compile time.  I've thought of putting "trace" statements all over the place to find out what could be null but I don't know what I'm looking for so throwing in trace statements might be pointless.

Comment: If I am understanding the final point of error correctly, doesn't it have to be something within the SpawnBlocks() method that is null?  I'd look at stageRef and vectorBlock, and perhaps block.pointsGiven.

Comment: Ok it seems it was the stageRef, it was null.  Would of been nice if it told me the stage was null and not the timer.  Ahh but now I'm getting a new error, should I start a new question or just edit this one?

Comment: Start a new one.  @Ribs: Make an answer from your comment, so @RamenNoodles can accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the final point of error correctly, doesn't it have to be something within the SpawnBlocks() method that is null? I'd look at stageRef and vectorBlock, and perhaps block.pointsGiven.

Answer (score 1):

this error usually occur when something is null, my best guess is "stageRef"
try adding

```
stageRef = new Stage();
```

before

```
this.stageRef = stageRef;
```

one more thing you can do for better debugging is to permit it, to do so click **file/publish settings/flash** and tick "**permit debugging**" and then republish it again to see your error, this time it will let you know  the frame and line number that's causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the info, ill do just that.

Comment: Plus one for the debugging tip.  I'm gonna check that out.

Comment: It seems my hunch was right. I shouldn't have deleted my comment :). Regardless, you should be listening for `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` instead of passing stage references. That way, no code will be executed (provided you use the logic to do so) unless the stage is not null.